Defined stuff, Index
So, I have seen in some books that they have index of defined stuff throughout the book at the end of the book, so you can find a definition of a notion you need much faster. Some books (for example Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry") have an amazing feature that they introduce all included notation in a separate index. Now, of course, you can do all this once you are satisfied with your text, but a suggestion on, say page 10, can derail your notation after page 10 to appear at different pages then you originally said. Is there a way, for example a command, or a macro or something, that gives you all stuff you defined and denoted throughout your text?
Thankies for the help. I am not a programmer, so sowwy if this is too trivial!

Are you maybe looking for https://ctan.org/pkg/acro or https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra  ?

Or \index and e.g. imakeidx, for example?
